# Grouping by first letter in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which lists the employee list. I want to show the list as below;

```
                    A
                    -----------------
                    asdas
                    adfgs
                    artret

                    B
                    -----------------
                    bifjgdifg
                    buasüdp
                    bpopo

                    C
                    ----------------
                    cxasdas
                    coierewf
                    clasdksa
```

How can I integrate this grouping type into mine report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in the SQL statement that returns the data by adding an additional column that only contains the first letter and is invisible in the report - group by that column then.

Another way could be to change the group-field in the report's group to not group by for example `=Fields!Name.Value`, but use a string manipulation function to group by only the first letter. For example you could try

```
= LEFT(Fields!Name.Value, 1)
```

for the grouping.